# Have the user input 3 names, put them in alphabetical order in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to put in 3 names, then puts it alphabetical order. I'm not too sure how to do it, but this is what I have so far:

```
students=input("Give me 3 names")
students.sort()

for student in students:
    print("%s here" %name)
```

I was thinking about defining the names since that seems to be the main problem with my code.

Comment: students is string, you have to turn it to list, eg `students = students.split()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start with an empty list, define how many names you want, then instruct the user each time with a loop that will append to the list. Finally, return/print your sorted list.

```
names = []
nameTotal = 3

print "Give me 3 names"

while len(names) < nameTotal:
    names.append(raw_input("name {0} ".format(len(names)+1)))

print sorted(names)
```

with 2.7 this returns:

```
Give me 3 names
name 1 Mandy
name 2 Arianna
name 3 Charlie
['Arianna', 'Charlie', 'Mandy']
>>>
```

Comment: this helps a lot and i'm getting the hang of it. thank you.

Comment: Great, I thought from your question you would want to be more explicit with the user, also lists are mutable, and strings are immutable.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is `students` is one string, not  3 in a list, so your `sort` won't work (there is no `str.sort`). Assuming that you input the 3 names separated by a space, split the input by a space:

```
students = students.split(" ")
```

This will return a list of all the 3 names that were separated by a space. Then sort it, and print. Also, you can omit the separator of `split` if the separator is whitespace (of any length), so this will do the essentially same thing in this case:

```
students = students.split()
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, do I have to define the names? I was thinking about this:
names=[ Bobby, Satchel, Chris]. I'm sorry for all the questions. I'm fairly new at Python.

Comment: @AThomas I'm not sure what you mean by "define the names"? The names will be strings inside the `students` list.